# Yocto: Why is struct module undefined during building an external kernel module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, yocto

I am trying to add the example external kernel module *hello-mod* from *meta-skeleton/recipes-kernel* to my image using the Yocto build system. When I try to compile it with `bitbake hello-mod`, however, it fails at a second stage complaining that `struct module` has no member named `name` on the line `.name = KBUILD_MODNAME,`. It seems as if `struct module` is not being defined even though *linux/module.h* has been included. This is the generic module code that doesn't seem to compile:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/vermagic.h>
#include <linux/compiler.h>

MODULE_INFO(vermagic, VERMAGIC_STRING);
MODULE_INFO(name, KBUILD_MODNAME);

__visible struct module __this_module
__attribute__((section(".gnu.linkonce.this_module"))) = {
    .name = KBUILD_MODNAME,
    .init = init_module,
#ifdef CONFIG_MODULE_UNLOAD
    .exit = cleanup_module,
#endif
    .arch = MODULE_ARCH_INIT,
};

#ifdef RETPOLINE
MODULE_INFO(retpoline, "Y");
#endif

static const char __module_depends[]
__used
__attribute__((section(".modinfo"))) =
"depends=";
```

I am unable to see anything wrong in the compilation log, make is being invoked (correctly, to the best of knowledge) with the following line:

```
make -C /path/to/poky-rocko/build/tmp/work-shared/duovero/kernel-source \ 
M=/path/to/poky-rocko/build/tmp/work/duovero-poky-linux-gnueabi/hello-mod/0.1-r0
```

and I can confirm that *module.h* exists in the directory:
*/path/to/poky-rocko/build/tmp/work-shared/duovero/kernel-source/include/linux*

So I am running out of and looking for ideas on how to debug this issue. For the record, these are the current versions of the layers, kernel etc:

- poky is 9915e071bcadd7c4d5363a067c529889851d37a5 (rocko) from git.yoctoproject.org
- linux is 9dc30ff9a115559cc55673d0b1d3c576402d073e from git.kernel.org

Any help or hints would really be appreciated!

Comment: "It seems as if `struct module` is not being defined..." - No, the error `struct module has no member named name` means that the structure is defined, but has no specified field. An error about using undefined structure type looks different.

Comment: Is the unmodified [example](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta-skeleton/recipes-kernel/hello-mod/files/hello.c) works?

Comment: I haven't modified the example, just included it into my layer. I agree that the error indicates that something is defining `struct module`, however, `struct module` as defined in `<linux/module.h>` definitely has a member called `name`.

Comment: Do you have `CONFIG_MODULES=y` in your kernel .config? That's probably a silly question because it shouldn't get to stage 2 if it is not defined, but the `struct module` full declaration does depend on the `CONFIG_MODULES` macro being defined.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Ian, as you guessed though, `CONFIG_MODULES=y` is indeed defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with the Yocto build system. The hello-mod module builds when I follow these steps.

1. Check out a version of the kernel 4.16.x, add hello-mod to `MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA` `_RRECOMMENDS` and watch the build fail.
2. Check out a copy of another kernel 4.16.y by setting SRCREV to the corresponding commit id, continue the build and watch it succeed.

So far I have observed this when moving from 4.16.5 to 4.16.8 and vice versa. So at this point I am pretty sure that this is an issue with the build system.

I had a close look at the output of `bitbake -e` using grep (against "hello" and "MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RRECOMMENDS") and diff but couldn't find any significant differences. I also checked the compilation and configuration logs, the only interesting thing I saw was in the configuration logs where on the second run this is printed:

```
DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure
NOTE: make KERNEL_SRC=/path/to/poky-rocko/build/tmp/work-shared/duovero/kernel-source clean
rm -f *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c
rm -f Module.markers Module.symvers modules.order
rm -rf .tmp_versions Modules.symvers
DEBUG: Shell function do_configure finished
DEBUG: Executing python function do_qa_configure
DEBUG: Python function do_qa_configure finished
```

while on the first run, we only have:

```
DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure
DEBUG: Shell function do_configure finished
DEBUG: Executing python function do_qa_configure
DEBUG: Python function do_qa_configure finished
```

Although this may have just occurred since this was the second run of the configure task for hello-mod. This seems very much like a bug in the build system to me. To this end, I have reported the issue on Bugzilla:

https://bugzilla.yoctoproject.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12748